# Grep whole path

Tags: linux, path, grep

I would like to do this:

```
ls * | grep pattern
```

But I would like, instead of just showing the file with the pattern, the whole path of the files that match the patterns.

Comment: So you want to look only in the current directory, but see the full absolute paths to the files, is that correct?

Comment: No, I want to look in all subdirectories. Sorry for not being explicit on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use `find` to do your matching, though you might have to change the pattern to match the `find` syntax instead of `grep`s as I think they are not identical.

```
find "$PWD" -maxdepth 1 -regex 'pattern'
```

should show you the full path and the `-maxdepth` will prevent it from going into subdirectories.  If you just want to use globs instead of regex you can use `-name 'glob'` syntax instead, and then use the `*` as you would with `ls`.

Here's an example output I see:

```
$ find "$PWD" -maxdepth 1 -regex '.*sh$'
/home/erenouf/tmp/scratch/t.sh
/home/erenouf/tmp/scratch/parseIW.sh
/home/erenouf/tmp/scratch/output.sh
```

since I was in `~/tmp/scratch` at the time and looked for files that ended in `sh`

In this case I can get the same output with

```
find "$PWD" -maxdepth 1 -name '*sh'
```

To have it look in subdirectories you can just remove teh `-maxdepth 1` part of each command

Comment: I made it work this way

`find | grep pattern`

For me it didn't work `find "$PWD"  -regex 'pattern'`

Comment: This last also worked `find "$PWD"  -name '*bed'`

Comment: @biorunner88 I suspect the regex one would work if your pattern was `'.*bed$'`, but if the glob works I'd go with that approach myself